# jQuery animation callback called too fast

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

So I am trying to animate `.load('content.html')` function by doing this.

```
function loadContent(c) {
    $('#main-container').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, 300, function() {
        $('#main-container').load('./content/' +  c + '.html');
        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
        }, 600);
    });
}
```

It is pretty straight forward, I want to animate opacity to `0`, load new content and animate opacity back to `1`. The problem is that content loads immediately after function is called so content changes before `'opacity 0'` happens. I tried also this piece of code

```
function loadContent(c) {
    $('#main-container').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, 300, function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#main-container').load('./content/' +  c + '.html');
        }, 600);

        $(this).stop().animate({
            opacity: 1,
        }, 600);
    });
}
```

But it is same result. Any hints?

I think it has something to do with `.animation()` event being **asynchronous**.

---

Both codes above, and both answers work just fine I had typo in my code (as whole) so I was calling `.load()` function before `loadContent(c)` itself, result was that content loaded immediately, animation started -> content loaded second time -> animation ended.

Comment: Try `$(this).stop().delay(1500).animate({ ...`

Comment: Tried, I also tried putting it before `.load()` did not work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass your last animation as a callback function to `load()`:

```
function loadContent(c) {
    $('#main-container').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 300, function() {
        $('#main-container').load('./content/' +  c + '.html', function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 600);
        });
    });
}
```

Here's a Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lp728/

Comment: I tried this before asking question, did not work, I think this problem has something to do with "animation event being asynchronous".

Comment: @Kyslik In what way did it not work? I would try again and make sure there are no syntax errors, because this will do the trick. https://api.jquery.com/load/ "Callback Function: If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed."

Comment: @Kyslik See my fiddle above.

Comment: Ok, I can see that in fiddle it works perfectly, but when I try it on localhost it does not work as expected (again content loads first->animate to 0 -> animate to 1). I am going to try it on live server, to see what happens + different browsers.

Comment: Even on live server it loads content first and after load it "blinks" (because new content is loaded already).

Comment: I would have to see more of your code to figure out where the error is.

Comment: I re-read my entire code (500 lines) and I found that I was calling initial `.load()` function even before `loadContent(c)`. Thanks to your last comment I solved it. (Even my initial code that is in the question works just fine.)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
function loadContentCOMMAS(c) {
    $('#main-container').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 300);
    $('#main-container').promise().done(function () {
        $('#main-container').load(c,function () {;
            $(this).stop().animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 600);
        });
    });
}
```

EDIT:

here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/r8U3u/)

Comment: Comma has nothing to do with this problem I think :) [after edit], I know what comma is for, and I know I can leave it there. (I tried removing it for the sake).

Comment: it does, your animate will not execute with the comme.

Comment: I think that only older IE have problem with comma on the last/only property.

Comment: you are right, the comma issue doesnt happen in chrome. i have changed my answer lol sorry about that :)

Comment: i have added an example